# ASP.NET 4.0 URL Routing - is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, routes

URL Routing - didn't working. Here is my code. A simple Example, don't know where i'm going wrong.??

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "Home-Route",
            "Home",
            "~/Channel/Index.aspx"
            );
    }

    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

whenever i tried to open this URL on my localhost "http://localhost/xyzProject/Home/". It shows 
'The page cannot be found
The page you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.'
One more thing, '~/Channel/Index.aspx' page is there and it is running.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `http://localhost//Home/` and not `http://localhost/xyzProject/Home/` ?

Comment: no, wrong..!! Virtual path always starts from its root project directory and i've tried it in your way btw thank you.